# When Mining on Testnet do I need to Sync again?

Tags: mist, testnets

I have fully synced Mist and have now switched to Test-Net and it appears the Sync process has begun again.

1. Is this now syncing the Test environment?
   if so then follow no:2
2. Can I only begin mining once the sync completes and -
3. Can I switch back to the main network without losing what has already 
   synced in the Test-Net?

Thanks

Comment: 1-yes 2-yes 3-yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are solo-mining, then yes you need to download the blockchain (it's separate testnet vs mainnet).

Yes solo-mining requires that you have the blockchain already up to date.

Yes you can switch back and forth without losing current status.